# Is there a way to zoom in to the centre of an object in d3?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q0ubpmwj/4/

When I zoom the rectangle goes off screen. What I need is the ability to zoom into this rectangle and stop if the next time i zoom it will go off screen. If you understand ?

I tried putting limits on the zoom using the `scaleExtent` but that doesnt seem to stop it from going offscreen.

What i need is the ability to pan around and stop the rectangle going over/outside the axis and also when i zoom for it to stop zooming when the rectangle goes over/outside the axis.

Appreciate any help or point in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this example last week when I was experiencing the same issue and it helped me out a lot. Hope it helps you as well.

http://bl.ocks.org/shawnbot/6518285

Comment: cheers dude will look tomorrow when im working on it again :)